# WPF suspending key presses for a slower movement

Tags: c#, wpf

In my game, my character is moving, but my problem is, that if I keep pressing the buttons he reaches supersonic speed and runs very fast. Which is not good.

What do you suggest how to put a "wait" in the code to simulate a more realistic moving?

I tried System.Threading.Thread.Sleep but it was a dead end. It suspended the whole program. And the enemies stopped.

I'm using a DispatcherTImer in the program for the enemy moving maybe it is the solution but i wasn't able to figure out.

I have this keydown event:

```
private void Window_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.H)
    {
        //Jatek.Player.Hack();
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.Up)
    {
        jatek.PlayerMovement(MozgasIrany.Up,Field);

    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
        jatek.PlayerMovement(MozgasIrany.Down,Field);
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.Left)
    {
        jatek.PlayerMovement(MozgasIrany.Left,Field);
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.Right)
    {
        jatek.PlayerMovement(MozgasIrany.Right,Field);
    }
}
```

This is how I move the characters:

```
public void PlayerMovement(MozgasIrany irany, Canvas Aktual)
{
    switch (irany)
    {
        case MozgasIrany.Up:
            player.Move(0, -10, MozgasIrany.Up);
            break;
        case MozgasIrany.Down:
            player.Move(0, 10, MozgasIrany.Down);
            break;
        case MozgasIrany.Left:
            player.Move(-10, 0, MozgasIrany.Left);
            break;
        case MozgasIrany.Right:
            player.Move(10, 0, MozgasIrany.Right);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public void Move(int x, int y, MozgasIrany irany)
{
    switch (irany)
    {
        case MozgasIrany.Up:
            if (alakzatTerulet.Y > 0)
            {

                alakzatTerulet.Y += y;
            }
            else
            {
                alakzatTerulet.Y = 0;
            }
            break;
        case MozgasIrany.Down:
            if (alakzatTerulet.Y < 420)
            {

                alakzatTerulet.Y += y;
            }
            else
            {
                alakzatTerulet.Y = 420;
            }
            break;
        case MozgasIrany.Left:
            if (alakzatTerulet.X > 0)
            {
                alakzatTerulet.X += x;
            }
            else
            {
                alakzatTerulet.X = 0;
            }
            break;
        case MozgasIrany.Right:
            if (alakzatTerulet.X < 610)
            {
                alakzatTerulet.X += x;
            }
            else
            {
                alakzatTerulet.X  = 610;
            }
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using the Rx framework. But, if you don't want to go there, then you could just store the time of last event processing and only accept the event if enough time has passed.  http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rx is the way to go

```
>         var keypress =
>                 Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(this, "KeyDown")
>                     .Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
>                     .Subscribe(
>                         args =>
>                         {
>                             if (args.EventArgs.Key == Key.H)
>                             {
>                                 //Jatek.Player.Hack();
>                             }
>                             else if (args.EventArgs.Key == Key.Up)
>                             {
>                                 jatek.PlayerMovement(MozgasIrany.Up, Field);
> 
>                             }
>                             else if (args.EventArgs.Key == Key.Down)
>                             {
>                                 jatek.PlayerMovement(MozgasIrany.Down, Field);
>                             }
>                             else if (args.EventArgs.Key == Key.Left)
>                             {
>                                 jatek.PlayerMovement(MozgasIrany.Left, Field);
>                             }
>                             else if (args.EventArgs.Key == Key.Right)
>                             {
>                                 jatek.PlayerMovement(MozgasIrany.Right, Field);
>                             }
>                         });
```

I am using Sample as a way to tame the keypresses, this will take the last event every 100 milliseconds but you can use other examples see here

http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html